# Python bus = smbus.SMBus(1) equivalent in C++?

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, i2c

I'm writing code to access an I2C sensor in C++ on a raspberry pi using wiringPiI2C.

I need to tell the pi whether to use smbus 0 or 1 (in my case, bus 1).

I know that in Python, this would be:

```
 bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
```

Do you know what the C++ equivalent of this would be?

Comment: _@wintermute_ You have a [sock-puppet](http://stackoverflow.com/users) now, or were you banned actually?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have no idea what you are talking about. I lurk on stackoverflow often and recently made an account to ask a question.

Comment: _@wintermute_ Well, you decided to share your nickname with some [other popular user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4301306/wintermute) on the [tag:c++] tag. That's why I'm wondering about who you actually are.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm just a neuromancer fan. I didn't know some other guy had this username. I'll probably just make another account if this is an issue.

Comment: Have a look at this link. https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/i2c-library/